# How to load image in recyclerview cardview from firebase storage using glide, firebaseUI?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-glide

I'm using firebase database(firebaseUI) for loading text in cardviews recyclerView, but my images are stored in firebase storage. How can I populate my cardviews with a different image for each cardview using Glide?

-Should I only use FirebaseUI database in my code(with Glide) with 'image' as key and the Firebase storage url as value, ie `{ image:FirebaseStorageURLOfOneImage }`? While manually uploading image to firebase storage.

-Or is there a way to use both FirebaseUI database & storage in my code(with Glide), and still load one different image per cardview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use FirebaseUI database in my code(with Glide) with 'image' as key and the Firebase storage url as value, ie { image:FirebaseStorageURLOfOneImage }

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PropertyViewHolder holder,
                                     final int position, @NonNull final Property model) {  
 holder.setPropertyImage(model.getPropertyImage());
}

//...code skipped...

 public void setPropertyImage(String propertyImage){
        ImageView imageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_propertyImage);

        // Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
        // (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
        GlideApp.with(getContext())
                .load(propertyImage)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

[image: database structure]